# Constitutionally, how is the Thai Prime Minister chosen?

Tags: election, constitution, thailand

How is the Thai PM chosen in the next (March 2019) election? What is the procedure laid out in the Constitution?

---

Wikipedia provides some information, however, it's not entirely clear to me how that applies to the next election. I will lay out three quotes from Wikipedia and then explain why these seem conflicting.

Quote 1 from the [appointment section of Wikipedia's page on the Thai PM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Thailand#Appointment):

> The Prime Minister of the Kingdom of Thailand must be a member of the House of Representatives.

Quote 2 from the [appointment section of Wikipedia's page on the Thai PM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_Minister_of_Thailand#Appointment):

> The nominee and eventual prime minister is always the leader of the largest political party in the lower house or the leader of the majority coalition formed after an election.
>
> Under the current junta, the nominee for the office is selected by National Legislative Assembly, with the House of Representatives being abolished.

Quote 3 from [Wikipedia's page on the 2019 Thai election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Thai_general_election#New_electoral_system):

> Under the new constitution, all 250 members of the Senate, Thailand's upper house, will be appointed by the NCPO and be able to select the next prime minister.

Quote 4 from [Wikipedia's page on the 2017 Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Thailand#2017_Constitution):

> The bicameral Parliament could also select a candidate as Prime Minister who is not one of its members or even a politician. That person could become Prime Minister if the appointed Senate approves.

---

These quotes seem to conflict quite a bit. Quote 4 suggests the PM could be an outsider, whereas quotes 1 & 2 indicate the PM is a member of the lower house and already has a senior political position, respectively. Quote 3 says the PM is selected by the Senate, but given quote 2 that would be a choice between at most two people (leader of the largest party or the leader of a majority coalition).